# when is pushforward of flat sheaf locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal L$ be a sheaf over $X$ that is flat over a map $f: X \to Y$, that is separable and of finite type between Noetherian schemes $X,Y$.

Under what conditions is the pushforward $f_* \mathcal L$ locally free over $Y$? I believe that this is the case when $Y$ is regular and $\dim Y=1$, because local regular rings of $dim = 1$ are PIDs. I am wondering if there are more general conditions that also guarantee local freeness of $f_* \mathcal L$.

Comment: Without properness?

Comment: Sure, add properness if you have to. Do we need properness also for the 1-dimensional result?

Comment: Even in the one dimensional case without properness direct image will not be coherent .

Comment: Hm. In my situation $\mathcal L$ is actually coherent  (finite vector bundle). Is that ok, without properness? Do you know a good reference for all this stuff?